# Super CSV & Dozer: Can't find SurveyResponse class

Tags: java, dozer, supercsv

I downloaded the 2.0.1 version of Super CSV and I configured an eclipse project to use it and the Dozer bean reader.
I am following this example as a first try: http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/xref-test/org/supercsv/example/dozer/Reading.html

But I'm stuck with the SurveyResponse class. In the .jar files I have ("super-csv-2.0.1.jar" and "super-csv-dozer-2.0.1.jar") there is no "org.supercsv.mock.dozer.SurveyResponse" and I don't know where to find it.

This is probably a noobish issue, but I need some help.

Thank you in advance,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this on the Super CSV [forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/discussion/718795/thread/e2f728a6/#8c9f) as well, but copied here for reference.

All of the project's examples are located in the project's tests, so they won't be included in the jars you can get from Maven or SourceForge.

We do publish the source and test source to the [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/xref-test/index.html) - it's the 'x-ref' items (for 'cross reference') under the documentation heading. Or just click the link above to go straight there!

If you use Subversion I'd recommend just downloading the Super CSV repository from SourceForge - then you can play with it to your hearts content. The `SurveyResponse` class is in the dozer module's test classes.

But if you don't, then you can download the file directly by using the Subversion web client by clicking [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/code/274/tree/trunk/super-csv-dozer/src/test/java/org/supercsv/mock/dozer/SurveyResponse.java).